# Will Ubuntu run on this Dell Precision 3510

Tags: dell

Does anybody have any idea how well Ubuntu will run on a Dell Precision 3510? If at all?

Full Spec:     Precision M3510
    Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-6300HQ Processor (6M Cache, up to 3.20 GHz)
    Windows 10 Pro (64bit)

```
8 GB (2x4GB) 2133MHz DDR4 Memory Non ECC

500 GB 2.5inch SATA Hard Drive (7200 RPM)

No Optical Device

Intel 8260 Dual band 2x2 802.11ac Wi-Fi + Bluetooth 4.1

No WWAN Card Included
Non Touch WWAN HD/FHD LCD Backcover

Non-Touch with Camera and Microphone

Primary 4-cell 62W/HR Battery

15.6 Inch FHD (1920x1080) Non-Touch Anti-Glare LCD
```

Comment: Please, please, please, stop asking these kind of questions! Just try running a LiveCD, or consult the recommended Ubuntu requirements!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It will run with no problem. I have very similar specification, no problem whatsoever.

Generally, Ubuntu and linux in general has no problem with hardware, there are some issues with specific graphic and wireless cards, tho.

Here is a official list of certified hardware. Please note, that if your model is not on the list, it doesn't mean it won't work.

https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/